# Can I trigger creation of tables on Analytcs Export completion?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have setup Analytics Export to BigQuery. Everytime when a new ga_sessions_yyyymmdd gets created I would like to run some queries aggregating some data for future use.

I can't figure out how to do this. Do I have to create a job and trigger it from outside or is there a way to trigger this in BigQuery directly (prefably using the Web UI).

Comment: You can contact your Google Analytics account manager they should be able to help you. Its that kind of support you are paying for :)

Comment: We're still trying to figure out who our Google Analytics account manager is :P To me, it sound more like a question that should be answerd in Googles support articles or here in the community though

Comment: Ok then. Wait I am sure someone will answer it here.  There are a few people that use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot schedule queries to run via the Web UI. You'll need to write a small piece of software to do this by using use the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/), and cron(s).

You may also want to check out [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) - bearing in mind that it's still in Alpha.

Comment: Thanks. My way forward as I see it, is to use the BigQuery API, write my software and publish it to the cloud. And then use the App Engine Cron Service to schedule execution of my script.